# Windows Container port binding not working on Windows Server 2016 (using Docker)

Tags: docker-container, docker-for-windows

I am running a Windows container using Docker on a Windows host (Windows Server 2016).I want to bind it to the host port 8000.and ran the container like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 474614/my_repo:javaprogram
```

Docker version:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ee-3
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3fcee33
 Built:        Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ee-3
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3fcee33
 Built:        Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

From my understanding, since I run docker "natively" from a Windows server with a Windows container, there is no intermediate VM (no docker machine) in between, so the "host" is the actual Windows Server that I run docker on.

So my question is, why does the host port binding not work? Why can I not reach the host ?

i tried to add the proxy through commandline by using the below command

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=8000 connectaddress="MY_HOST_IP" connectport=8000
```

What I also find confusing is that when I run netstat on both the host and the container, I get the below results

**netstat on host**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -ab | findstr ":80"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             MYCOMPUTER:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8000         MYCOMPUTER:0     LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:80                MYCOMPUTER:0      LISTENING
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

**netstat on container**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -ab | findstr ":80"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             MYCOMPUTER:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8000         MYCOMPUTER:0     LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:80                MYCOMPUTER:0      LISTENING
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

but when i try to access localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000 from my host machine i get shown the below error

```
This site can’t be reached

PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run 474614/my_repo:javaprogram
Hello Java
```

when i run the image i will get the above result. i'm trying to view the result through a browser and how would i do that? Is it possible to assign the ip on dockerfile while building the docker image? if so kindly help me with the sample dockerfile or Any advise on this would be helpful.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's bug in current implementation of networking in Windows. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2016/20160525-windows-nat-winnat-capabilities-and-limitations)

> Accessing internal endpoints directly from the Host Internal endpoints
>   assigned to VMs or containers cannot be accessed using the external
>   IPs / ports referenced in NAT static port mappings directly from the
>   NAT host. From the NAT host, these internal endpoints must be
>   addressed directly by their internal IP and ports. For instance,
>   assume a container endpoint has IP 172.16.1.100 and is running a web
>   server which is listening on port 80. Moreover, assume a port mapping
>   has been created through docker to forward traffic from the host’s IP
>   address (10.10.50.20) received on TCP port 8080 to the container
>   endpoint. In this case, a user on the container host cannot directly
>   access the web server using the externally mapped ports. e.g. A user
>   operating on the container host cannot access the container web server
>   indirectly on http://10.10.50.20:8080. Instead, the user must directly
>   access the container web server on http://172.16.1.100:80.
>
> The one caveat to this limitation is that the internal endpoint can be
>   accessed using the external IP/port from a separate, VM/container
>   endpoint running on the same NAT host: this is called hair-pinning.
>   E.g. A user operating on container A can access a web server running
>   in Container B using the internal IP and port of
>   http://10.10.50.20:8080.

Comment: This does not work for me.
Tried all the options:
<container ip>:8080
<container ip>:80
<host ip>:8080

Answer (score 1):

I am a PM lead on the Microsoft Windows Core Networking Team. This response is correct (although I can't upvote it). We will be adding support for localhost communication in the next Semi-Annual Channel (SAC) release of Windows (targeting Q2 CY2018). You can sign up to get Insider builds (before official GA) and this functionality should be included in those builds in the next few weeks.

Comment: Was this meant as a comment to the other answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. BTW Please remove this answer and post it as a comment to the existing answer (Stackoverflow rule).

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your package.json include this parameters in your "ng serve" entry ...

[image: ng serve]